# How to remove _id from collection in mongodb using mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Tried to remove _id from collection but not working. I do not know how to resolve this issue. Need help anyone.

model.js:

```
const schemmaodel = new mongoose.Schema({
  "name": { type: string}
}, { _id: false, versionKey: false });
```

data.controller.js:

```
var newModel = require(path.resolve('./models/model.js'))(collectionName);
newModel.create({}, function(err, doc) {
});
```

Comment: try deleting _id after receiving the document. `delete doc._id`

Comment: @Doc-Han:How do it? Can you update my code?

Comment: @Doc-Han: You have any solution?

Answer (score 0):

`_id` is like a primary key for the collection. If `_id` is not specified in the Schema then Mongoose will by default `_id` of type `ObjectId`.

As per the mongoose [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#_id) you can disable `_id` on subdocuments only. So in your case, `schemmaodel` is considered as parent schema and since you have set `{ _id: false }` option on parent schema while saving  it will throw an error related to missing `_id`